Convex conjugate of integral functionals
I want to compute the convex conjugate of the following class of functionals (Bolza integral):
$ F[u] = l(u(0), u(T)) + \int_a^b{L(t, u(t), u'(t))dt} $
I want to check whether there is a procedure for a general case of l and L that avoids solving the Euler Lagrange equation and that does not assume convexity of the functional F.
I think that by definition it should go like this:
First I rewrite the integral as:
$F[u] = \int_a^b{\delta (t)l(u(t), u(t + T)) + L(t, u(t), u'(t))dt}$
Then I search for the supremum of the following integral.
$F^*[p] = \sup_{u} \{ \int_a^b p(t)u(t) - (\delta (t)l(u(t), u(t + T)) + L(t, u(t), u'(t))) dt\}$
Finding the supremum with respect to u requires looking at the stationary solution which requires solving the Euler Lagrange equation. I am interested in knowing if there is a procedure for finding the convex conjugate which avoids solving the Euler Lagrange equation.

I think that you would need to narrow down the scope of your broad question to get an answer.
